# Can I install Linux on a USB flash drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, redhat-enterprise-linux

I want to install Red Hat Linux on my flash drive. Is there a way that I can do this?

I tried a lot found through searching, but couldn't get a satisfactory answer. In fact, if I try the same for Windows, I get so many links and tools – but for Linux I got nothing helpful.

I found [pendrivelinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/), but that didn't really help me either.

Comment: Is this question supposed to be about Linux or about Windows?

Comment: @Larry: No, he should wait until someone kicks it there.

Answer (score 2):

Try [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

> UNetbootin allows you to create bootable Live USB drives for Ubuntu,
>   Fedora, and other Linux distributions without burning a CD. It runs on
>   Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X. You can either let UNetbootin download
>   one of the many distributions supported out-of-the-box for you, or
>   supply your own Linux .iso file if you've already downloaded one or
>   your preferred distribution isn't on the list.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you always use the same USB port, you can directly install many Linux distros directly to a USB drive, and use it like you would a regular system.

Alternately, Fedora (which is a Red Hat variant – same tools, just swap your Red Hat ISO where it wants Fedora) has a [proper LiveUSB option](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_Live_USB), which is preferred since it reduces writes on your drive by only saving the differences from your base image.

I'd recommend running the [HP drive format tool](http://www.bay-wolf.com/usbmemstick.htm) if you're doing the install in Windows to ensure the USB key is bootable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, install it like you are installing on a hard disk.

- Just select the proper drive (may be /dev/sdb1 or similar).
- Make sure to install the GRUB on the USB drive only.
- Some linux distributions need you to enable usb HOOK in /erc/mkinitpcio.conf and recreate the kernel image.

See also -> https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_Arch_Linux_on_a_USB_key

Answer (score 0):

I just tried UNetbootin from the Sourceforge link on Ubuntu and it didn't work for me.

But `"apt-get install unetbootin"` worked like a charm.